# How can I tell if a file is text using PHP?

Tags: php, linux, text, file-type

I'm making a search engine for our gigantic PHP codebase.

Given a filepath, how can I determine with some degree of certainty whether a file is a text file, or some other type? I'd prefer not to have to resort to file extensions (like `substr($filename, -3)` or something silly), as this is a linux based filesystem, so anything goes as far as file extensions are concerned.

I'm using RecursiveDirectoryIterator, so I have those methods available too..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the [`finfo_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function.

Here's a blog describing its usage: [Smart File Type Detection Using PHP](http://designshack.co.uk/articles/php-articles/smart-file-type-detection-using-php)

Comment: Sweet.. a lot slower than I was hoping it'd be, but I guess it'll have to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mime_content_type($path) == "text/plain") {
 echo "I'm a text file";
}
```

Comment: Yes, but note that it's deprecated as of PHP5.3 in favor of `finfo_file`

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) utility:

```
echo `file '$file'`;
```

Returns things like:

```
$ file test.out
test.out: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped

$ file test.cpp
test.cpp: ASCII C program text

$ file test.txt
test.txt: ASCII text

$ file test.php
test.php: PHP script text
```

Comment: Bill Karwin's suggestion (finfo) uses the same libraries as the file utility. It will be much faster though, because it's a php extension

Comment: @Evert True enough, and definitely the way to go if you have the extension along with PHP >= 5.3

Comment: Is this not a command line utility? Which is majorly dependent on the OS of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:
`string mime_content_type  ( string $filename  )`

Hope this is helpful.

William Choi