# PHP Function that checks if file is a text file

Tags: php, function

So I made this file editor assignment for school and my teacher is well satisfied with the results. Yet he has one thing that he wants me to change:

At the moment I'm reading every file in a directory but im checking for each extension if I want to make it editable. That means I have to add an extension in the if statement each time a new extension needs to be added.

My teacher told me theres a function that returns true if the file is a text file like .html, .css, .php etc. and if its a .exe, .gif etc. it will return false. He's too lazy to give me the name of the function.

So.. What's the name of it? I've been trying to look it up but I just can't find the name of the function..

Edit:

fine lol hes not lazy

Comment: *He's too lazy* - I don't think so, I think he probably wants to teach you how to do research :)

Comment: maybe, I never know what hes trying to say.. hes a sophisticated guy and he looks like a mad scientist, lol

Comment: Technically, **all** files are text. It's just that some of them look like digital vomit. If you mean readable text, then that's a different beast. One person's readable text is still another's digibarf.

Comment: As a hint, you want information, about a file. There's a PHP module that exists to do that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670593/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-text-using-php this should help you down the road...

Comment: He may be lazy, but you follow close :PP [First result for "php check file is text on google"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670593/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-text-using-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quote:**

Try the [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) function.

Here's a blog describing its usage: [Smart File Type Detection Using PHP](http://designshack.net/articles/php-articles/smart-file-type-detection-using-php)

**Taken from:**
[How can I tell if a file is text using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3670593/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-text-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

`$ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);`[Pathinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) Then check for $ext.

Comment: I'm already using this method and this isn't dynamic because I would have to add another extension in my ifstatement each time a new extension needs to be utilized in my site :)